# IOException: Sharing Violation when attempting to modify a file in the Assets folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In one of my controllers (built for controlling time), I have the code set to save the current time of day as an integer between 0 and 2 in a text file in the Assets folder. However, in runtime when it tries to execute, it throws `IOException: Sharing violation` when I try to do so. Code:

```
 File.Create(Application.dataPath + @"\Variables\TimeOfDay.txt");
 File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + @"\Variables\TimeOfDay.txt", timeOfDay.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call **File.Create**. **File.WriteAllText** will create the file if it doesn't exist.

**File.Create** returns a file stream which prevents your next call to **File.WriteAllText** from accessing it and throws the sharing violation error.